# Como obtener un GameObject por tag que empiece por unos caracteres especificos? C sharp en Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity

Quiero definir un objeto que elimine todos los tipos de plataforma, que son prefabs, diferentes cuando colisionan con el.

El metodo es el siguiente:

```
   void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D _col){
        if( _col.gameObject.tag == "Platf_1" ||  _col.gameObject.tag == "Platf_2" || _col.gameObject.tag == "Platf_3"){
           _col.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            Destroy(_col.gameObject, 0.5f);    
        }
    }
}
```

Quisiera saber si mediante un metodo de strings en c# puedo definir que se eliminen todos los GameObjects que detecte que empiecen por `Platf_`

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usar el **método Contains** el cual verifica si una subcadena se encuentra dentro de otra cadena:

```
if (texto.Contains("Platf_"))
{
   //Hacer algo
}
```

También podrías usar el **método IndexOf** el cual devuelve el índice donde empieza la subcadena dentro de la cadena original, si no se encontró la subcadena se devuelve **-1**:

```
if (texto.IndexOf("Platf_") != -1)
{
   //Hacer algo
}
```

Personalmente te sugiero que uses el **método Contains**.

Comment: ¿Sé que es un caso raro pero, que pasa si es `-2`? Lo ideal sería usar un mayor que.

Comment: Si es un número negativo indica que no se encontró la sub cadena dentro de la cadena, pero usa el método Contains que en este caso es mucho mejor